Compensation for wrong worktime calculation
Tom works at a company in Germany. His regular work time is 8 hours daily, which is recorded via punch clock. He can collect overtime up to 40 hours and use it, for example, to leave early or to take paid days off.
However, when he started working 5 years ago, HR accidentally entered the wrong daily worktime into the punch clock system. Instead of 8 hours, they entered 8 hours and 5 minutes. Until now, Tom never noticed and so each week, he worked on average 40 hours 25 minutes, but only got paid for 40 hours.
Today, Tom noticed and contacted HR immediately.
Can he expect compensation, for example by having the time added to his overtime savings?
5 minutes do not seem much, but 5 minutes each day over 5 years accumulates to a decent amount.

that's oddly specific...

I strongly suspect that different years would be treated differently. There are statutes of limitation to civil claims.

@Trish One guess is that this comes after a reinterpretation of what exactly constitutes work time. For example, employees need to pass through a security gate before they can punch their clocks. It was recently ruled that the time at the security gate counts as work time. The employer accounts for that by giving everyone 5 min more worktime per day that what the punch clock says. How far back does this apply?

@Trish I added details because I hoped that it helps with understanding. Should I remove some?

The second paragraph runs counter to common sense. I.e. Tom should know the actual hours he worked if he starts and stops on the hour, and if the payroll computer is programmed to add 5 minutes to this time, he would actually be overpaid, right? He would only be underpaid if the computer subtracted 5 minutes off his punched times. It seems to me that you've misworded your description of the actual situation.  VTC for needing clarification.
